# Where can I find documentation on Firebase Cloud Messaging available sounds?

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase

I'm trying to use the default iOS "note" sound for FCM. I can't find any documentation on Firebase with a list of available sounds for iOS.

For reference, below is the notification format I'm sending. With this, I simply get the default sound used for voicemail:

```
{
  notification: {
    title: notification.title,
    body: notification.body,
    badge: String(_.size(unreadNotifications)),
    sound: 'note'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used FCM yet, so I'm not exactly sure which sound you're referring to. If it's a sound included in the framework, you should be able to use the filename I think (with extension I believe). If it's an iOS sound, [this list of sounds might be what you need](https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary).

Comment: The documentation you linked to is "from 2.0 to 5.0 beta". Do you know of documentation for more recent versions of iOS?

Comment: @AndrewHenderson I updated the link to a GitHub project. Seems to be the most recent.